# Shouldn't users get to ask one more question after the warning for bad questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, post-ban

I recently found that I had a warning about asking bad questions and that I might lose the privilege, so I decided to stop asking anything until I felt certain my question was very good and interesting.

Today was the day I felt my question was worth asking but sometime between being warned and today I lost the privilege.

To me, it defeats the purpose of warning me if I don't get a chance to change my behavior.

Would it make sense for Stack Overflow implement some sort of "last chance" question that comes with the warning?  Does a warning system make sense without a chance to step back and re-approach more carefully?

Comment: It would certainly make sense, as the last thing you'd want to do is post in haste only to end up with a guaranteed block thanks to a rushed question. I'm not sure whether the blocking algorithm makes this feasible to implement, though.

Comment: To be clear, the likely reason you're no longer eligible to ask today is that voting activity on your questions pushed you past the threshold sometime between the warning and today. But all is not lost - as stated in the help article, you can always improve your existing questions so they're up to snuff with your future question.

Comment: I assumed this is what happened.  The thing about my past questions, though, is that they are all pretty decent IMO.  One of the most negatively voted ones was completely dismissed as pointless and dumb by users.  I later found the exact answer to my question at `go help gopath`.  Apparently it was something the developers of go really felt was worth answering.   And none of the users were willing (or likely knew) to share that information.... point being, I don't think I did such a bad job.  But I'm still willing to limit myself to topics of interest if need be.

Comment: @SephReed well, to see what you can do to get the ban lifted, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)